# How to apply a function on \1 in sed?

Tags: bash, function, sed

How do I apply a function over a numeric remembered pattern in sed?

Simplifying the problem, it is as below:

file.txt:

```
130 Some string here
40  Some string here
19  Some string here
```

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

function tenmore
{
expr $1 + 10
}

sed -i.backup "s|^\([0-9][0-9]*\)\t\(.*\)|\2\t`tenmore \1`|g" file.txt
```

wantedoutput:

```
Some string here    140
Some string here    50
Some string here    29
```

what I actually get:

```
Some string here    11
Some string here    11
Some string here    11
```

So, it interprets \1 as an escape of the character 1, and executes the function over 1 (1 + 10 = 11), not over the numeric value stored in \1. How can I apply functions over \1 ?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think sed can do that.. This is exactly was perl was created.

Comment: If you use bash, don't use expr. It's very inefficient. use $(($1 + 10)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to use awk, or do not want to rewrite your bash function:

```
( echo -e "130\tSome string here";
echo -e "40\tSome string here";
echo -e "19\tSome string here" ) | while read v1 v2; do echo -e "$v2\t$(tenmore $v1)"; done
```

Comment: Oh, I did just that with cat file.txt instead before the pipe and it worked just fine. Which made me curious: how does the "while read" knows which is v1 and which is v2 since I haven't defined it? It assumes so because of the tab separators? If you have any good online reference of how this works, I would love to have a look, very useful.

Comment: man bash, and look for the `read` built-in function that should point you to the IFS shell variable.  But careful with piping to a script (I should have told in the answer), as a variable set in the `while ... done` will not be available in the next commands because the pipe starts a new context.  The `while ... done < file.txt` might be safer.  If useful, please accept the answer ;-).

Answer (score 1):

awk is the right tool for that:

```
( echo -e "130\tSome string here";
echo -e "40\tSome string here";
echo -e "19\tSome string here" ) | awk -F "\t" '{print $2 "\t" $1+10}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The backtick expansion happens in the shell, before the sed program is ever started, so it cannot know that \1 will have a special meaning to sed.

Things like this is a good case for moving from sed to a stronger tool, such as Perl:

```
perl -p -i.backup -e 's/^([0-9][0-9]*)\t(.*)/"$2\t".($1+10)/e'
```

or even

```
perl -p -i.backup -e 's/^(\d+)\t(.*)/"$2\t".($1+10)/e'
```

(The /g modifier is pointless when your regexp matches only at the beginning of the line)

Comment: I am not familiar with the Perl syntax, what does the -e, -p do? And the /e at the end? Also not sure if I understand the "$2\t".($1+10).

Comment: Oh, most important: my $1 + 10 example was didactic. The actual function is quite more complicated, span over several lines and would be incredibly ugly if expanded in this one-liner, if at all possible. Any way I can actually apply a function?

Comment: -p instructs Perl to "act like sed, passing one line of input through the script and printing what's left in the buffer afterwards". -i is as in sed. -e means "the following argument is a script, rather than the name of a file that contains a script". /e means "the second part of s/// is an expression that produces the replacement text, rather than the replacement text itself". "$2\t".($1+10) takes matched subgroup 2, appends a tab, and then appends the result of the expression $1+10.

Comment: You cannot use a _shell function_ from within either Perl or sed. I would advice you to learn enough Perl (or awk or whatever) to write your function as part of the Perl script instead of as a shell function. There's (famously) a learning curve, but it will be time well spent.